# Unable To Get Crontab To Run Bash Scripts

Tags: bash, unix, centos, cron

Good Morning All,

I'm currently having an issue with running a bash script in Crontab on my CentOS 6.5 system. I believe that I have all of the permissions set correctly for the bash scripts and the scripts are set to be executable.

Basically, I'd like to run the below scripts 4 times a day for each model run (00Z, 06Z, 12Z, 18Z) and I thought that I had that setup correctly but, apparently not.

Here's what I have set in crontab (via the " crontab -e"):

```
40 02 * * * /home/muaddib/grads/get_nomads/bash/nam4.sh
30 08 * * * /home/muaddib/grads/get_nomads/bash/nam4.sh
15 14 * * * /home/muaddib/grads/get_nomads/bash/nam4.sh
20 20 * * * /home/muaddib/grads/get_nomads/bash/nam4.sh

40 02 * * * /home/muaddib/grads/get_nomads/bash/nam12.sh
30 08 * * * /home/muaddib/grads/get_nomads/bash/nam12.sh
15 14 * * * /home/muaddib/grads/get_nomads/bash/nam12.sh
20 20 * * * /home/muaddib/grads/get_nomads/bash/nam12.sh

39 02 * * * /home/muaddib/grads/get_nomads/bash/gfs_sflux_t2m.sh
30 08 * * * /home/muaddib/grads/get_nomads/bash/gfs_sflux_t2m.sh
15 14 * * * /home/muaddib/grads/get_nomads/bash/gfs_sflux_t2m.sh
48 22 * * * /home/muaddib/grads/get_nomads/bash/gfs_sflux_t2m.sh
```

I tried to run them last night but, nothing happened...

Any thoughts?

Comment: The crontab is executed as the user it belongs to.  This user needs to have the proper permissions to see and execute the files.  You _are_ doing this as user `muaddib`, right?  And you have double-checked the paths?  If run manually as exactly the user of the crontab, then it works?

Comment: what do you mean by saying `nothing happened...`? check `/var/log/cron` to see whether the jobs were triggered

Comment: Try adding something simple and build it up from there, e.g. * * * * * /bin/date > /tmp/date.tmp. Then make a little script at /home/muaddib/grads/get_nomads/date > /tmp/date.tmp

Comment: To make that clear:  What you posted does not seem to contain an error (unless we all fail to see it), so probably the problem is in something you didn't post.

Comment: You may need to indicate the binary that is needed to execute the script --> `40 02 * * * /bin/bash /home/muaddib/grads/get_nomads/bash/nam4.sh`

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone! Unfortunately, I still am unable to get this to work. Quite frustrating...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Check mail after login as muaddib,

```
su - muaddib
mail
```

It gives you the error message from cronjob and you should find out what's the reason.

2) The common problem in cronjob is, you need provide full path for each command in script, or run the script in cronjob as:

```
20 20 * * * ~/.profile; bash /home/muaddib/grads/get_nomads/bash/nam4.sh
```

If the script is written under bash

Answer (score 0):

Were you able to run these script successfully standalone?

There is possibility that your script needs application specific 'Environment variables' for eg. "LD_LIBRARY_PATH"

Also, you can try with simple test script that will echo some text in test.txt file and include it in crontab. If it runs you will be sure that there is not an issue with crontab.

Let us know if this works!

Answer (score 0):

I spent about 2 hours trying to figure this out myself, maybe it'll help someone else.

Just because your script is /home/user/scripts/script.sh and in your crontab you call that script by the absolute path, doesn't mean that's the path that the script is actually running in.  I found the output of my script in /home/user, which makes some sense in retrospect.  Make sure if the script you're calling is generating output that you specify the full path to the output inside the script as well (or cd to the correct path at the top of the script).